# Flutter Textbutton doesn't reset instant

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

I was trying to code a TikTakToe game in FLutter but failed at the point where I tried to make a **button which resets** the fields.

```
class TikTakToe extends StatefulWidget {
  const TikTakToe({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TikTakToe> createState() => _TikTakToeState();
}

class _TikTakToeState extends State<TikTakToe> {
  int currentindex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal[100],
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Tik Tak Toe"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.teal[400],
        ),
        ...
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          gameOver = true;
                        });
                      }, child: const Icon(Icons.refresh))
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

bool gameOver = false;

class Field extends StatefulWidget {
  const Field({Key? key, required this.fieldnumber}) : super(key: key);
  final int fieldnumber;

  @override
  State<Field> createState() => _FieldState();
}

class _FieldState extends State<Field> {
  String playersign = "";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
      child: Text(
        gameOver ? "" : signlist[widget.fieldnumber],
        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 60),
      ),
      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
          side: BorderSide(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 88, 221, 208), width: 2),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.zero),
        ),
        enableFeedback: false,
        primary: Colors.amber[800],
        fixedSize: const Size(120.0, 120.0),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          
          
            
    ... Winner evaluation

            }
          }
          }
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Now I have the problem that the buttons (Fields) are actually resetting but only after clicking on them and not instant after clicking the reset button In the TikTakToe class.

The only thing that worked was adding
(context as Element).reassamble(); to the onPressed of the Elevated button

```
setState(() {
   gameOver = true;
   (context as Element).reassemble();
});
```

but I got this warning:

The member 'reassemble' can only be used within instance members of subclasses of 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart'.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change *gameover* variable place into _FieldState class.

```
class Field extends StatefulWidget {
  const Field({Key? key, required this.fieldnumber}) : super(key: key);
  final int fieldnumber;

  @override
  State<Field> createState() => _FieldState();
}

class _FieldState extends State<Field> {
  String playersign = "";
  bool gameover = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
      child: Text(
        gameover ? "" : signlist[widget.fieldnumber],
        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 60),
      ),: const TextStyle(fontSize: 60),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `gameOver` variable inside of Field widget and dont forget to use camelCase in naming variables, on the other hand you have to pass `onPressed` to `TextButton` if you dont want to be clickable just pass `onPressed: null`

```
class Field extends StatefulWidget {
  const Field({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Field> createState() => _FieldState();
}

class _FieldState extends State<Field> {
  String playerSign = ""; 
  bool gameOver = false; // put var inside
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        TextButton(
          onPressed: null,
          child: Text(
            gameOver ? "" : signlist[widget.fieldnumber],
            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 60),
          ),
        ),
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              setState(() {
                gameOver = true;
              });
            });
          },
          child: const Text(
            "reset",
            style:  TextStyle(fontSize: 60),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image: result]

- suggest to read [this doc](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style)

Comment: The problem is that I have an extra button to reset the fields outside of the Fields class. I tried doing it with (context as Element).reassamble() and it worked but i got a warning.

Comment: Its better to show the warning and full code, we cant understand your problem untill you show errors.

Comment: I edited it now, im pretty sorry for the trouble

Comment: I tried your code but i dont know what is wrong again, you have some widgets that idk what it is!